# set cookies on certain page only

Tags: headers, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie on Wordpress on a certain page only. I've tried a LOT of different ideas but still can't get it to work as 'init' is called before the page is set.

This is my current code:

```
add_action('init', function() { 
    //if ( is_page( 2164 ) ) {  
        setcookie( "my_cookie", 'hello' );
    }
});
```

But of course is_page() won't return the current page and nor does anything else I try.

I've looked at other suggestions on StackExchange (e.g. using 'templateredirect') but they don't work for me either.

So has anyone any idea how I can set a cookie when a user hits a certain page only?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you very, very sure hooks like `wp` and `template_redirect` do not work? And btw, it's not "templateredirect".

Answer (score 0):

Please try to create certain page template and set cookies

```
<?php
/*
    Template Name: Certain Page
*/

setcookie('my_cookie', "hello", (time()+3600), "/");
get_header(); 
?>
```